# Please verify the result which i get using grep for korn shell

Tags: shell

when i run the command  `ps -ef | grep ksh` on my server  i get the result as -

`/bin/ksh` `./abc.ksh` `./xyz.ksh`

where abc and xyz are my shell scripts.

what does this symbolize ?
Is  one script calling the other one ?

and why do we use ampersand after nohup ?

Answer (score 0):

`ps -ef`  diaplays all processes running on the system 
`grep ksh` filters lines which contain the string `ksh` literally

what is displayed as a result of your command does not have any significance, as far as which script runs which one, as you put it. But if you look at the actual output you get, on the second and third columns, you will see the PID and PPID, which are Process ID (unique for each process) and Parent Process ID. By looking at the parent process ID of a process you can tell which process started that one.

Lastly `&` at the end of `nohup` statement tells the shell to run it in the background, not taking up the terminal screen, so that you can exit from your session and `nohup` still keeps it running